# what is the difference between the functions getAddUrl and getAddToCartUrl?

Tags: magento

I have found two function returning the exactly same value.

`getAddUrl` in `\app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Cart.php`

`getAddToCartUrl` in `\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php`

what is really the difference between these two?as I am adding an add to cart button in my block.
Which function should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the example below

```
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($_cartUrl=$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)): ?>
   <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_cartUrl ?>" class="link-cart"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

getAddUrl can fetch you URL of the helper you associate it with, eg: wishlist, compare, etc.
but getAddToCartUrl will only get you the add to cart URL for the product passed to it.

I hope it clarifies things for you

Comment: Thanks @sanket I got it now. Thankyou.
Can I pass the array of the product to getAddToCartUrl, because when I am doing this I got an error on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Does your block inherit the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` class? If so you should use the getAddToCartUrl method of the block.

Otherwise you should use the helper, there is no neat way of calling a block method without creating the block in this case a product block.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these two functions is that the `getAddToCartUrl` (`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`) will return product view page URL if product has required options. 
And `getAddUrl` (`Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart`) will always return url for add product to cart.